# Unable to connect to host mysql in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

I want to connect to host mysql in container, and I have tried some methods but none of them work.

Container: python & mysql client

Host: mysql service

Host mysql setting:

```
sudo apt install -y mysql-server
apt install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev

# And modify bind address: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf 
# bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Docker container run command's setting:

```
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt install -y default-mysql-client &&\
    apt-get install -y gcc &&\
    apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev &&\
    /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&\
    pip install --no-cache-dir SQLAlchemy
```

My python file in container:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql://root:pwd@localhost:3306/mysql?charset=utf8mb4"
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, encoding='utf8', pool_pre_ping=True) # for mysql

with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(text("show tables;"))
    print(result.all())
```

Envrionment:
Ubuntu: 20.04
Docker version: 20.10
Mysql version: 8.0

My purpose is to connect to mysql throught sqlalchemy in container, but not even through mysql-client.
[image: sqlalchemy connect fail]
Therefore, I try to use mysql-client to connect, but still failed as same reason.
[image: through mysql-client]

[image: use host.docker.internal]

I have tried several method:

- allow bind-address
- run container with: --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway
- without --add-host, try IP address

Most of the solution just say add --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway and it can work,
But not work for me.

Does anyone solve this problem?
Thanks!

---

Update:

I have tried a method that works.

1. run container --network=host
2. (in container)# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root ...

But I don't want to use --network=host, how can I connect to host mysql with "host.docker.internal"?

---

Update:

Problem solved.
I run container with --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway

connect to db with: mysql -h host.docker.internal

And in mysql, update mysql.user root's host to '%'.

**(allow non-localhost connect)**

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. Using `mysql` without `-h` or `--host` by default tries to connect to localhost via a socket file.
2. Using `mysql -h host.docker.internal -u root -p` is correct. However, as the error message states, you'll need to provide permission for the root user to connect via non-localhost. If using the mysql container, run with `-e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%` or similar set.
3. I don't know which command you're using to start the mysql container. Make sure you're publishing the ports with `-p 3306:3306` to all for cross-container communication.